# Python: Searching a list inside a list 1 index at a time

Tags: python, list

I am a quite new python coder and would like some help with going through list entries 1 by 1. In my current code, I have a multiple lists inside a main "ballots" list and would like to go each entry 1 at a time. If the first entry is a 1, can1v1 would +=1. If it's a 2, can1v2 would +=1. If it's a 3 can1v3+=1.

This would continue for each position in its list (if the 2nd index of the first lis is a 1, can2v1+=1, if it's a 2 can2v2+=1, if it's a 3 can2v3+=1 and this would continue until the last position of each list where it it's a 1 2 or a 3, the can5vsomething would +=1. I would like the code to continue doing this for each list inside of the main ballot list. Please can anyone help me with how I can do this where I go through each list and position individually? My code is as follows: 
pastebin.com/Pi3NwWaq
This is the list:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '0', '0'], 
 ['1', '3', '0', '2', '0'], 
 ['1', '2', '3', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '3', '2', '0', '1'],  
 ['1', '3', '0', '2', '0'],  
 ['2', '0', '3', '1', '0'],  
 ['0', '0', '2', '1', '3'],  
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '0'],  
 ['0', '1', '0', '2', '3'],  
 ['2', '3', '1', '0', '0'],  
 ['3', '2', '0', '0', '1'],  
 ['0', '1', '3', '2', '0'],  
 ['0', '0', '1', '2', '3'],  
 ['0', '0', '3', '2', '1'],  
 ['1', '2', '3', '0', '0'],  
 ['2', '1', '3', '0', '0'],  
 ['0', '3', '2', '1', '0'],  
 ['0', '2', '3', '0', '1'],  
 ['1', '2', '3', '0', '0'],  
 ['1', '0', '0', '3', '2'],  
 ['2', '1', '3', '0', '0'],  
 ['3', '1', '2', '0', '0'],  
 ['2', '3', '0', '1', '0'],  
 ['0', '0', '3', '1', '2'],  
 ['0', '3', '1', '0', '2'],  
 ['2', '1', '0', '0', '3'],  
 ['2', '0', '0', '1', '3'],  
 ['2', '0', '0', '1', '3'],  
 ['3', '0', '1', '0', '2']]
```

Comment: Use the code blocks, that hurts my eyes

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Now post your code, not the pastebin

Comment: My desired out put is for can1v1, can1v2, can1v3 all the way to can5v3 to have the relavant number of how many times their number has been stated in the ballots.

Comment: For example, in the first list only; can1v1:1 / Can2v2 = 1/ Can 3v3 = 1.

Comment: In the 2nd list only: Can 1v1 = 1 / Can2v3= 1/ Can4v2 = 1

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question, you can access the items in a list like this:

```
ballots=[['1', '2', '3', '0', '0'], ['1', '3', '0', '2', '0'], ...['3', '0', '1', '0', '2']]
sub_ballot=ballots[0] #this gets the first sub list, you'll have to iterate through them all
vote=sub_ballot[0]  #this gets the first vote in the first sub_ballot list, you'll also have to iterate through these
```

I'll leave the rest to you.

P.S.

This would be way easier using dicts

Edit:
try this

```
for sub_ballot in ballots:
    for i,vote in enumerate(sub_ballot,1):
        #if conditions etc
```

Note that i will be the index of the vote in the sub_ballot list, and it will start at 1 rather than the normal 0.

Comment: I'm trying to use this:  for (sub_ballot,votes) in range(ballots_quantity): and it where ballots_quantity is the quantity of lists above, however, it keeps saying that an INT isn't iterable, what would you reccomend?

Comment: That's because you are basically saying `for each-one-of-these in this`. But `each-one-of-these` is a tuple (similar to a list), and so it's trying to fit that into the integer that you get from the range function, which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can index particular entries like:

```
ballots[i][j]
```

Where the entry is in the ith list, jth entry (counting from zero).

To iterate through everything, a nested for loop should work:

```
for sub_ballot in ballots:
    for vote in sub_ballot:
        "All of your if statements here"
```

Answer (score 0):

if I've understood correctly you really want to count the occurances of '1', '2', '3' in each column

there's python idiom that 'transposes' a 2D nested 'array' like yours:

`zip(*ballots)` is the 1st step in doing the whole problem without indexing,
 not that you shouldn't start there and work up to `zip`, `list comprehensions`, methods like `my_things.count(item)`

but I can't resist the 'one-liner':

> [[o.count(c) for c in ('1', '2', '3')] for o in zip(*ballots)]
>
>     [[7, 8, 3], [7, 6, 7], [4, 5, 11], [7, 6, 2], [4, 4, 6]]